# Returning connected socket returns null

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to create an client - server app on android. I want to have a class that initialize the socket and returns it to the main class. I don´t have any problems creating and connecting the socket (my server is handling the connection properly) but when I try to return that created socket to the main class it is null. What am I missing?

I have tried using AsyncTask.

This is the code of the main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket socket;
    private SocketHandler sH;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sH = new SocketHandler();
        sH.start();
        socket = sH.getSocket();

        if(socket == null){
             System.out.println("null");
        }else{
            System.out.println("not null");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of the class that initialize the socket:

```
public class SocketHandler extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;

    public Socket getSocket(){
        return socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            socket = new Socket("192.168.0.4", 9999);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like a race condition

Comment: You call `start` on the `SocketHandler`, which starts a new thread that will at some point initialize the `socket` variable. You then call `getSocket` in `MainActivity`, but there is no guarantee at that point that the `socket` variable already has been initialized (that happens in a separate thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread are run in parallel which means it is NOT guaranteed that you socket connection would complete immediately, yet you falsely assume that and you step on classic race condition, because at the moment you call `getSocket()` the connection is still being established (but this process has not yet completed), therefore `socket` variable is still `null` as it was initialized upon creation of instance of your `SocketHandler`.

You need to synchronize the code, do a callback or (for testing purposes) either wait a bit before you call `getSocket()` or read couple of times (i.e. in a loop + some delay/timeout unless socket value is not `null` (but mind you need to expect `null` to be also valid value if socket connection fail).

Also, why you read the socket in main thread if you create in in separate thread? shouldn't you be doing all the socket work in that thread anyway?

Comment: True, thank you! I will create two classes (that will extends on thread) that will be waiting for server messages and sending responses to the server so I can´t do both in the same thread.